# problem with dynamic class loading in java

Tags: java, class, dynamic, classloader

hi i have a code that's loads a class file into my program. when i run/debug it from eclipse i always chose the class file from my bin directory. when i compiled my program into a JAR file the loading doesn't work.
those are the lines that load the class file

```
public void load_dynamic_tag(String file_path)
            throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException,
            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        File f = new File(file_path);// some folder's path
        URI uri = f.toURI();
        URL url = uri.toURL();
        URL[] urls = new URL[] { url };
        // create a new class loader for this directory
        ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        // load the class file "MyAlgo.class"
        String name = f.getName();
        name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf("."));
        name = "Tagging." + name;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<TaggingStrategy> c = (Class<TaggingStrategy>) cl.loadClass(name);
        // TaggingStrategy tag=c.newInstance();
        tag = c.newInstance();
    }
```

this is the error i get

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Tagging.Tag_by_lenght_filename
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at Tagging.Tags_all.load_dynamic_tag(Tags_all.java:233)
        at Command.LoadTagCommandExecutor.execute(LoadTagCommandExecutor.java:24
)
        at GUI.DropBox$2.handleEvent(DropBox.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
        at GUI.DropBox.showGUI(DropBox.java:168)
        at GUI.Try_control$5.handleEvent(Try_control.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
        at GUI.Try_control.<init>(Try_control.java:161)
        at GUI.NewSWTApp$2$1$2.run(NewSWTApp.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
        at Service.Main.main(Main.java:79)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

what am i doing wrong?
tnx allot

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the file path no longer works, your class is inside the .jar file, and thus an ordinary File won't do. 
What you need to do is to locate the class file within the .jar file:

```
File myFile = new File(YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()));
JarFile myJar = new JarFile(myFile);
```

Then get entries inside the jar as follows:

```
Enumeration entries = jar.entries();
```

Now, see documentation on `Enumeration` how to list class files. (Loop over all files, select those ending in .class) From here, you know class name, and can therefore load it.

Comment: and if i want to add a class out of the jar file?

Comment: if the class file is NOT in the jar file, you should be able to just provide with an absoulute path. Note that the package that class is inside must match the directory structure, see example on http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/LoadClass.html (Also, maybe you need to substitute the slashes in the path with a dot), className = classPath.replace('/','.')

Answer (score 1):

Actually all you need to do, is putting your jar file in the class path and call

```
Class<TaggingStrategy> c = (Class<TaggingStrategy>)Class.forName("Tagging.MyAlgo");
```

If "Tagging.Tag_by_lenght_filename" is the correct name of the class you want to load, your problem is most probably simply that your jar is not in the class path.

If you do not want to have the jar in your class path, you need to create an URLClassLoader with an URL pointing to your jar file:

```
URLCLassLoader myCL = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File("path/to/myjar.jar").toURI().toURL()});
```

If you want that your code works in both cases, you need to make sure that your URL is pointing to the bin directory in eclipse and pointing to the jar file in case you want to use a compiled jar file.

If you need to discover which class files are available you could use the FileSystem abstraction layer ([FileSystems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html)) which can create a FileSystem from either a directory or a jar file.

Answer (score 0):

A URLClassLoader looks in directories and jar files for a class. Whatever you pass in as "file_path" would need to be a path to either a jar or directory containing the class you're looking for. If a directory, it should end with a "/". Maybe you're using a relative file path, which would have different meanings based on where it's running from. What's being passed in, and where does the class live?

Comment: i tried sendin a full path using  
Path p = Paths.get(class_file_path);
  File class_file = new File(p.toAbsolutePath().toString());
but it didn't work

Comment: Yes, read my answer again. The path to the class file is useless. Give it a directory or jar file, exactly as if you were adding a directory or jar to the classpath for compiling or running. E.g. if your class is com.foo.Bar, the file will be at <some dir>/com/foo/Bar.class. You'd need to pass "<some dir>" to the ClassLoader in order to be able to find class Bar.